Can't cast from Windows 11 - device is visible, but says "couldn't connect" and "your device doesn't support Miracast" (it does)
On a new Lenovo Legion 16IRX8 running Windows 11 23H2, with up-to-date drivers for BIOS, Intel Graphics, and wireless adapter, I cannot cast media to my TV. Opening the Cast menu (Win+K) shows the tv as a wireless display, but clicking on it immediately displays a red "couldn't connect" error. Underneath that is a message: "Connect a cable to cast. Your device doesn't support Miracast, so you'll need to connect an external display with a cable." (This is untrue; this hardware does support Miracast). If I go to Settings > Bluetooth and other device settings > Connect a new device > Wireless display or dock, the tv is similarly visible, but adding it similarly returns "couldn't connect."
I have already tried the generic troubleshooting google has to offer (pc and tv on same LAN, wifi adapter mode is 802.11a/b/g, GPU enabled in BIOS, DxDiag reports "Miracast: Available, with HDCP," Cast to Device allowed in firewall, all related services running).
It's absurd that a new, powerful computer can't perform this basic function. Any ideas what's going on?

Btw, please don't flag this as a duplicate question. There's a couple similar questions about miracast not working, but they're all 5-10 years old and were "Solved" by such revelations as "airplane mode was on/wifi was disabled," "computer has no wifi card," "wifi card has no antenna," and "graphics was disabled in BIOS," which are not useful or technical solutions.

Here is the honest truth, Miracast isn’t supported by modern GPUs from Intel, Nvidia, and AMD support for it was removed from their drivers awhile ago. Miracast came with multiple requirements often unknown and unspecified except if you did hours of research on the subject. One of those requirements was that the wireless device also had to specifically support it. I am sure you will disagree with this comment based on your meta commentary.

If by "wireless device" you mean the tv, yes it supports it. I tested it by casting from a different windows laptop, and it worked just fine. Regarding Miracast not being supported by modern GPUs, what you're saying makes sense, it's just hard to believe! I never would have guessed that the most powerful modern hardware would regress in capability like this

No, I mean the WiFi adapter. Miracast support is vague wrapped in absence of details wrapped in a decade of vague specs that never seem to match up. The hardware support it, the driver doesn’t, Miracast became irrelevant with technology like Chromecast unfortunately

Here's an interesting development. While going to devmgmt > update driver gives the standard 'the best driver is already installed' message, picking to manually select the driver, and then filter by compatible hardware, shows TWO VERSIONS of the same driver. I figured the 1st on the list was probably what's installed so I selected the 2nd. After installing it, pressing Win+k NO LONGER SHOWS "Your device doesn't support miracast, connect a cable..." (actually clicking a device in the list still says "couldn't connect," but it takes a sec before showing that error instead of immediately!)

any update since this was originally posted?

Nope, haven't had a lot of time to experiment with it though. I'm close to doing a fresh Windows install and checking to see if it can cast, then redoing my setup and check casting intermittently to try to pinpoint where it stops working. But that's a big hassle and not high on my priorities rn unfortunately
